# TelerikGrid in Blazor, Filter is taking to much time for big data set

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using TelerikGrid for Blazor WASM project.

```xml
<TelerikGrid Data="@MyData"
        @ref="@Grid"
        ScrollMode="@GridScrollMode.Scrollable"
        Pageable="@pageable"
        PageSize="_itemsPerPage"
        Height=100%
        Sortable="true"
        FilterMode="@GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
        FilterMenuType="@FilterMenuType.CheckBoxList"
        Resizable="false"
        SelectionMode="@GridSelectionMode.Single" 
        RowHeight="_rowHeightPX"
        Reorderable="false">            
    <RowTemplate Context="ctx">
        <td>@ctx.Id</td>                        
    </RowTemplate>      
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(EmpDTO.Id))" Title="EMP Id"/>
    </GridColumns>    
</TelerikGrid>
```

I have more than 10k records for Id in my Database. When I click on filter icon in Grid, its taking long time to display the records in the filter list to filter the grid.
Can you please suggest, how can I improve the performance of Filter for huge data set.

Note: Tried Using FilterMenuTemplate, but still same issue exist.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine But If i use OnRead, it will take only available Id on the screen to display in the filter list.. But I want to load all the Id from complete Grid Data

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I already tried by Creating the List of Ids separately and using FilterMenuTemplate, I bind it in filter list. But still no improvement.

Comment: You are talking about filtering with Telerik system after the records have been retrieved from DB, I suggested to filter directly the records when requesting them from DB.

Comment: You should do a pagination and serverside filtering thats how it works for me

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine This project is WebAssembly not server side.